# Domain User Lists

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2

I work in a domain environment and noticed that there are a list of users showing up in the Users folder. The list includes users from within the same department and also users of other departments controlled by the domain . Some of the users have never logged on to the specific computer that they are showing up in. 
Is this normal or might I suspect some variant of malware  ???

Comment: Look in the windows security logs in the event viewer. This will tell you how those directories got created the user doesn't have to login to create there profile directory. Only an application needs to run in there context, for example when a user logs in as another user using a UAC prompt.